# CSS Flex-box justify-self / align-self not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, semantic-ui

I have a component in React using [Semanti UI react](https://react.semantic-ui.com/)

I am trying to justify a single container to the flex-end but it's not working

```js
<Item  key={item._id} id={item._id}>
           <img className="image" src={item.imageURL} alt="Project Canvas"/>
           <div className="content">
              <div className="title">{item.title}</div>
              <Item.Meta>
                {new Date(item.createdDate).toUTCString()}
              </Item.Meta>
              <Item.Description>{item.description}</Item.Description>
              <div className="footer">
                <Button primary floated='right' href={item.workURL} target="_blank">
                  Go to application
                  <Icon name='right chevron' />
                </Button>
                <Label color='teal' tag> React </Label>
              </div>
           </div>
         </Item>
```

the component that I am trying to flex-end is the **< div class="footer">**

My CSS

```css
.content{
  margin: 1vh !important;
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column !important;

}

.footer{
  padding-top: 2vh !important;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,173,181,1) !important;
  justify-self: flex-end !important;
  align-self: flex-end !important;

}
```

the justify-self  and align-self doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have defined your layout using `display: flex`.

`justify-self` will be ignored, i.e it will have no effect.

It will only have effect when you have used `block` or `grid` or have positioned an element using `absolute`.

You can read more on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self).

With `display:flex`, following properties are supported.

```
justify-content: flex-end; // horizontal axis when flex direction is row.
align-items: flex-end: // vertical axis when flex direction is row.
```

So if you are trying to place the footer at right-bottom of your parent container i.e `content`.

Try this :

```
.footer{
  padding-top: 2vh !important;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,173,181,1) !important;
  justify-content: flex-end !important;
  align-items: flex-end !important;

}
```

Comment: I want to emphasize that you can still use `justify-self` to override the behavior of individual elements if you replace your flexbox with a grid.  To make the grid more of a drop-in replacement for your flexbox, you can set its `grid-auto-flow` to `column`/`row`.